# RoR: Nested Form with Many fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

There are any way to have a nested form which is like:

Client has_many address
In the Client _form.html.erb there are the normal Client fields and an :
      `<%= f.fields_for :local do |ff| %>`
to add the address fields too

My question is how do i put two or more fields_for to add two or more addresses?

```
   def cliente_params
     params.require(:cliente).permit(:name, :telefone, :celular, :email,      :local_attributes => [:logra, :cep, :uf, :city, :km])
   end

  def new
    @cliente = Cliente.new
    @cliente.build_local
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you have a `client` that have many `locals` (addresses). If so, You can do something like the following:

```
@cliente = Cliente.new
2.times { @cliente.locals.build }
```

And then, in your form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :locals do |ff| %>
```

Comment: It worked wonderfuly. But there are one more thing to make things work like i need, in 2.times it puts other form in view, ok, there are anyway to make this be specified by the user? by default i'd like to let only one and if needed the user can add one more, i have an jquery to clone nodes and append but it doesn't INSERT into the table.

Comment: you could send the quantity in the `params`, but there is a [gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) that does exactly what u want. I have created a simple [demo](http://nestedform.herokuapp.com/) a long time ago... feel free to explore the [code](https://github.com/gabrielhilal/nested_form)

Comment: Oh, i have this gem installed, but i couldn't figure out how to use it propely, i'm really new to rails so it take time to understand anything

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, following your demo, i could make exactly what i needed

Comment: Can i make another question? There's a way to make a nested inside a nested? like a have this Project which has many Tasks which has many task1 which has many task 2 which has many task3, and i want all of them in same form, i made this follwing ur DEMO, but it's INSERTING only Task and Task1

Comment: I have never done that, but i'm sure it is possible. There is a [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) about it, and also a [demo](https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/nested_form)